# Combining plt.plot(x,y) with plt.boxplot()

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, boxplot

I'm trying to combine a normal matplotlib.pyplot `plt.plot(x,y)` with variable `y` as a function of variable `x` with a boxplot. However, I only want a boxplot on certain (variable) locations of `x` but this does not seem to work in matplotlib?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Are you wanting something like this?  The `positions` kwarg to `boxplot` allows you to place the boxplots at arbitrary positions.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Generate some data...
data = np.random.random((100, 5))
y = data.mean(axis=0)
x = np.random.random(y.size) * 10
x -= x.min()
x.sort()

# Plot a line between the means of each dataset
plt.plot(x, y, 'b-')

# Save the default tick positions, so we can reset them...
locs, labels = plt.xticks() 

plt.boxplot(data, positions=x, notch=True)

# Reset the xtick locations.
plt.xticks(locs)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you, this is exactly what i wanted. Iwas always trying to do something like plt.plot([x,y]) in boxplot, but failed ... seemsi misunderstand the kwarg `positions`

Comment: +1 for showing how to conserve the xtick locations. When working with axes the commands are `locs = ax.get_xticks()` and `ax.set_xticks(locs)`

Comment: Additionally to my comment above one actually needs to add `ax.set_xticklabels(locs)` as well to get the labels right.

Comment: Great answer without the need to use seaborn! Great!

Answer (score 0):

This is what has worked for me:

1. plot box-plot
2. get boxt-plot x-axis tick locations
3. use box-plot x-axis tick locations as x-axis values for the line plot

```
# Plot Box-plot
ax.boxplot(data, positions=x, notch=True)
# Get box-plot x-tick locations
locs=ax.get_xticks()

# Plot a line between the means of each dataset
# x-values = box-plot x-tick locations
# y-values = means
ax.plot(locs, y, 'b-')
```